# How to print info about a randomly selected item

Tags: python, random

I want to print information about a randomly selected item. I am doing a project in class that needs a price and information about something that you buy from a store, but I can't figure that out. Sample code looks like this

```
import random

def test():
    items = ['thing', 'item']
    thing_info = 'Price is 4, gives you stuffs'
    item1 = random.choice(items)
    print item1, item1_info
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Recommend that you make a class to represent each item, with a name and an info field. That way you just `random.choice()` your list of items and print the fields that are relevant.

Comment: So is this a question how to store different information types in one object? Making a `class()` as suggested @Bilkokuya is probably the way to go. Nevertheless, you should make your question more precise. While I can imagine, put e.g. the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

To hold related information about an object together, classes are a good design tool to use.

There is a lot of information out there on how to use classes, best practices etc. And so I am only going to give a basic example from which you can find more information.

```
import random

class MyItemType:
     def __init__(self, name, info): # a "constructor" in other languages
         self.name = name
         self.info = info

items = [ MyItemType("thing", "first description"), MyItemType("item", "price is 4")]
selected_item = random.choice(items)
print(selected_item.name, selected_item.info) # prints either "thing   first description" or "item   price is 4"
```

Any further explanation of how classes work is far outside the scope of this answer.